# CMYK 2 RGB Problem

Tags: colors, cmyk

I have a problem with converting a CMYK Color to RGB. 
In the internet there is many formulas to convert it but for example when I convert CMYK (0,100,100,0) to RGB, it get value (255 0 0) but in Adobe Photoshop RGB value is (237,28,36) and I want this one. Is anybody know how to convert it with java or .NET?

Answer (score 4):

There are other questions asking the same thing:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rgb+cmyk
- [How to convert CMYK to RGB programmatically in indesign](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2667887/how-to-convert-cmyk-to-rgb-programmatically-in-indesign)
- [Convert RGB color to CMYK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2426432/convert-rgb-color-to-cmyk)

The general gist of your problem is that Photoshop is applying a Color Profile where-as you are simply doing a direct conversion.  Please see my answers to some of the other questions as I feel like I've answered this question to death.

Answer (score 3):

If you want good result, you need to apply a color profile. In .NET, you can do it like that (assuming the the original CMYK components are in the range between 0 and 255):

```
float[] colorValues = new float[4];
colorValues[0] = c / 255f;
colorValues[1] = m / 255f;
colorValues[2] = y / 255f;
colorValues[3] = k / 255f;

System.Windows.Media.Color color = Color.FromValues(colorValues,
    new Uri(@"C:\Users\me\Documents\ISOcoated_v2_300_eci.icc"));
System.Drawing.Color rgbColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(color.R, color.G, color.B);
```

Note that two different *Color* classes from two different namespaces are used. And you probably need to add the *PresentationCore* DLL as a reference.

The required color profile can be downloaded from the downloads section of [eci.org](http://www.eci.org). It's part of a bigger ZIP file containing several profiles. They explicitly recommend to use the *ISO Coated v2 300% (ECI)* profile.

There's a nice web site showing the [CMYK to RGB color conversion](http://www.codecrete.net/CMYK) with the color profile at work.

If you need to convert a complete image from CMYK to RGB, there are special classes for this in the same namespace.

Answer (score 0):

if you want photoshop like cmyk conversion then use JDeli java image library ; there is a class called EnumeratedSpace which does the job for you;

please do not forget to bit mask because return values are rgb bytes

Answer (score -1):

[ColorJizz](http://code.google.com/p/colorjizz) can convert from RGB to CMYK and many other formats. There's a .NET version in there.